# Connection refused error in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

This code is generating "Connection Failed error", (the error generating portion is commented below in the code) even when i am supplying the correct input format eg.

> ./Client ip text portno
>
> ./Client 127.0.0.1 "tushar" 7100

```
//AUTHOR: TUSHAR MAROO
    //Client.c
    //header files used
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>


//constants
#define RCVBUFFERSIZE 32
//functions used
void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);

//main program
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
unsigned short serverPort;
char *serverIp;
char *message;
unsigned int messageLength;
char buffer[RCVBUFFERSIZE];

//condition check deplyed for nuber of arguements not for data in arguements
if((argc<3) || (argc>4)){
    fprintf(stderr,"Format: %s <Server's IP> <Your Message> <Port Number>\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}

serverIp = argv[1];
message = argv[2];

if(argc == 4){
    serverPort = atoi(argv[3]);
} else {
    serverPort = 7;
}

//create a socket and check success and handle error
if((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0 )
    fprintf(stderr, "Socket Creation Fail");

//server details
//bzero((struct sockaddr_in *)(&serverAddr),sizeof(serverAddr));
memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverIp);
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
printf("tusharmaroo");

//not working why??
//if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
    //DieWithError("Connection Error..");
    //fprintf(stderr,"Connection error");
//this snippet also not working 
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithError("connect() failed");

printf("connected....");
messageLength = strlen(message);
if(send(sock, message, messageLength, 0) > 0)
    printf("message sent....");
    
    
close(sock);    
exit(0);
}
```

```
//AUTHOR TUSHAR MAROO
//SERVER CODE
//header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

//constants declared
#define ALLOWEDCONNECTIONS 5

//external functions
void DieWithError(char *error);
void ClientHandle(int sock);

//main code
int main(int argc, char argv[]){

    int serverSock;
    int clientSock;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    unsigned int serverPort;
    unsigned int clientLength;
    
    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"Format: %d <Port No.>", argv[0]);
        //DieWithError("Pass Correct Number of Arguements...");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if((serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0){
        DieWithError("Socket not Created");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    serverPort = htons((argv[1]));
    //assign address to the server
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);
    
    //socket has been created now bind it to some ip and port
    if((bind(serverSock,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr))) < 0){
        DieWithError("Binding Failed");
    }
    
    if(listen(serverSock,5) < 0){
        DieWithError("Listen Failed");
    }
    for(;;){
        clientLength = sizeof(clientAddr);
        if((clientSock = accept(serverSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &clientLength)) < 0){
            DieWithError("Accept() failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        printf("Handling Client %s ",inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr));
    
    }
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Is there anything listening on that destination (ip-port)?

Comment: @KirilKirov yes, a server is listening, and working fine.

Comment: If you're sure (can be checked with `netstat`), that this port is opened and listening, then you should check the server's logs (if any) to see why it does not accept the connection.

Comment: What is function return value?

Comment: Struggling to understand the two upvotes.

Comment: @AlexFarber value is -1.

Comment: What's the errno, though?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein how to get the errorno?

Comment: @TusharMaroo - you need to `#include <errno.h>` first. Then you can print it as a normal variable `errno` and you can see its description by printing `strerror( errno )`.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein the errno is 111.

Comment: Next step is to either use `perror`, as Paul Rubel mentioned in his answer, or to `grep` or google 111 in errno.h.  It comes out to connection refused.  That says that either the server isn't listening fine, or doesn't like what you're passing it.

Comment: @TusharMaroo - can you post the output of `netstat -a`, relevant to this port number? And can you check the logs of the server?

Comment: If `perror` is showing a Success message, we'll need to see your latest code.  Are you sure there's still an issue connecting?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Sorry to trouble you all but i think now the issue is in Server.c file. :( should i include above that too?

Comment: That, and the output from `netstat -a` that Kiril is asking you for. :-)

Comment: @KirilKirov the output of netstat -a is [link](http://pastebin.com/9HFaXTu6)

Comment: @TusharMaroo - I don't see opened port `7100` in this report.

Comment: @KirilKirov is the server code error free? if erroneous code is there please point it out. it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in the server code

```
 serverPort = htons((argv[1]));
```

This should be

```
serverPort = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
```

Comment: Unless he's running on a Sun :) The netstat should tell all.

Comment: please check the server code, is there any more mistakes, i corrected that one you pointed out, but still not working :(

Comment: Hello Tushar, Could you pl. use 0 as the 3rd argument of socket function, instead of IPPROTO_TCP in both the client and server codes and check if this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are no firewall rules causing troubles for you? Ensure that.

If the connect fails you should be able to print out the error using perror or strerror:

```
perror("Could not connect:");
```

Answer (score 0):

works for me

client and server are ubuntu 12.04

for server, run in a shell

```
nc -l 9999
```

This is on a host with the address "192.168.56.13"

for client, compile code above with "DieWithError" fixed up

```
void DieWithError(char *errorMessage) {  printf("%s",errorMessage); exit(1); }

cc -o foo foo.c
./foo 192.168.56.13 "hello" 9999</strike>
```

replace the DieWithError() with perror()  Then I would guess that it will print out "connection refused" as you seem to have a networking problem with getting the server running on the correct address.

However, if the address in your client is correct the nc program WILL print "hello"

***you just altered your program*** the previous version worked for me.  The current version, I don't know if it does.

Like everyone else is saying, use perror() to get proper diagnostics